# Trigger multiple functions same time from website

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a very simple application.

The user uploads a photo, then the photo gets various enhacements such as 'blur' or 'sepia'.

The processing of the image filters, is done in azure functions. So you pass the 'guid' of the image to the azure function along with the filter, then the azure functions takes care of it and creates the photo and puts in in azure storage.

I have multiple image filters.

Is it ok to do from my website, multiple requests to azure functions in the same time for each filter? Or is there another way.

Note: i do not want to use blobstorage triggers since they can have a couple of minutes delay. Thats what i read on microsoft official documentation.

I am thinking that making 100 parallel http requests on a webserver might be overkill. What is the alternative to trigger 100 parallel function execution.

Comment: this will probably bee closed as its too broad, and can essentially result in someone saying Yes   or No.   As you have only asked if its okay.    On a side not,   if you ask for it to be blurred, and in a separate request ask for it to be XXX   will that be applied to the blurred?   who wins on save?

Comment: I just want to process multiple images same time, then show a gallery to user. Why so hard to explain.

Comment: Also give a look at Durable Azure Functions. Durable Functions allows you to implement Function chaining concisely in code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview

Comment: what i was saying is, if you fire,  make bigger, and fire blur image and fire, make black and white.   all at same time.  one function is going to win.  I.E  one is going to be writing, whilst another is.  so who gets to write, also is blur added to the black and white, or do you get one blurred and one black n white.  Also your question does not ask how to show 100 images.  it ask how to apply a filter, 100 times, in parrallel

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using HTTP for this task and fire 100 parallel requests to your Azure Functions. Getting this to work 100% reliable might be a challenge though, be sure at least to retry if some of the responses are of non-success status code.

A more natural way would be to refactor to event-driven Functions.

One option can be Azure Event Grid as described in [Reacting to Blob storage events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview). Event Grid is fast, but I can't find any reference to guaranteed latency for Blob events. It also seems that you might need 100 Functions in this case, which sounds bothersome.

Finally, you can just send 100 messages to a Storage Queue or Service Bus Queue, saying which blob needs to be processed and with which transformation inside message payload. Functions runtime will take care of scaling and parallelizing executions based on the queue statistics.

Comment: Latency is very important thing, it is written in official documentation that if you have more than 10.000 blobs then it can take up to a minute for them to be processed.